# How to reduce the bandwidth size in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, bandwidth

I have to test performance of project with 20kbps and 40kbps using Jmeter.

I am digging how to set up bandwidth in Jmeter.
 
Please help me how to set up it in Jmeter.

Will the below configuration control bandwidth thing?
Or any other configuration is there?

```
# Define characters per second > 0 to emulate slow connections
httpclient.socket.http.cps=1024
httpclient.socket.https.cps=1024
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Is-jmeter-can-be-used-to-simulate-network-bandwidth-td533487.html).

```
To emulate a bandwidth of, say 100kbps, define a CPS of 
( 100 * 1024 ) / 8, i.e. 100kB divided by 8, so, that would be
httpclient.socket.http.cps=12800.
```

Then refer to your summary listener for confirmation this is working.

Comment: Does this work for a regular TCP Sampler or do you have to use HTTP Requests, etc.?

Comment: I don't think so. It is config for the http client.

Answer (score 0):

We always used a 3rd party tool to throttle bandwidth during performance testing, as Jmeter doesn't have a good way to do this.

Comment: Care to tell us _which_ 3rd party tool you used?